# Error al intentar función de la librería random

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un error que dice esto

> File "randomizer(1.0).py", line 16, in 
>   codigo>         key = randrange(0, 6)
>       NameError: name 'randrange' is not defined

ya tuve este error antes y lo solucione pero aca no veo nada malo en el código para que no se importara la librería en `PYTHON 3.8.1`, sospecho que esto es un error de una mala importación en la librería pero no se como arreglarlo. Estoy usando `randrange` de la librería `random` de `python 3.8.1`

mi código:

```
#this app make a list and the random lib thing random choose a list thing

import random

print("randomizer++")

print("1. dados")

print("2. provincias de argentina")

print("3. numeros (solo para pc poderosas)")

opc = int(input(""))

if opc == 1:
 key = randrange(0, 6)
 print("el numero es "+ key)
 input("Presiona ENTER para salir")
 exit()


if opc == 2:
 list = ["Buenos Aires", "Catamarca", "Chaco", "Chubut", "Cordoba", "Corrientes", "Entre rios", "Formosa", "Jujuy", "La pampa", "La rioja", "Mendoza", "Misiones", "Neuquen", "Rio negro", "Salta", "San juan", "San luis", "Santa cruz", "Santa fe", "Santiago del estero", "Tierra del fuego", "Tucuman"]
 print(random.choice[list])
 input("Presiona ENTER para salir")
 exit()


if opc == 3:
 n1 = int(input("Pon el 1er numero: "))
 n2 = int(input("Pon el 2do numero: "))
 print("Generando numero entre", n1,"y", n2,".")
 key = randrange(n1, n2)
 print("El numero random es",key)
 input("\nPresiona ENTER para salir")
 exit()
```

Answer (score 4):

Cuando importas el módulo mediante: `import random` debes establecer el espacio de nombres al invocar alguna función del mismo, es decir, deberías invocar la función de esta forma: `key = random.randrange(0, 6)`. Sino, mucho mejor es, establecer que objeto o función particular del módulo vas a importar mediante:

```
from random import randrange
```

y ahora sí, será valido hacer:

```
key = randrange(0, 6)
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo al lectura de [What are the “best practices” for using import in a module?](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module)